# Search for string in a nested list (python)

Tags: python

I have a nested_list = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['b','d']] and i have target element of 'b', how would i search through this list to return list containing element, hence ['b', 'c'],['b','d'] ?

I have tried but it is only giving me ['b', 'c']:

```
for elem in nest_list:
   for item in elem:
      if 'b' in item:
        return elem
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you return the item, and once the return statement is reached, this loop isn't run again. If you were to replace `return elem` with `print(elem)`, you would see both results being printed out.

If you want to return both values, then you can create another array which appends your results and then returns it outside the for loop:

```
returnList = []
for elem in nest_list:
    if 'b' in elem:
        returnList.append(elem)
return returnList
```

Note that you can also remove one of the for loops since `in` checks within a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for elem in nest_list:
   for item in elem:
      if 'b' in item:
        print(elem,end=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
nested_list = [['a'], ['b','c'], ['b','d']]

output = [sublst for sublst in nested_list if 'b' in sublst]
print(output) # [['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]
```